# Postgresql + python (как связать)

Tags: python, postgresql

Имеется веб сервер на ubuntu

На него установлен:
python 3.9
Postgresql

Не могу связать эти 2 объекта.

1. Припереклбчении на пользователя "postgres", могу подключиться к базе, вижу таблицы и в целом проблем с доступом нет (по аналогии был создан пользователь "mywebsiteuser")
2. Python приложение, если запускать без обращения к postgresql - работает корректно.
3. Танцы с бубнами и пересоздание пользователя с новыми правами не принесло успеха, проблема остаётся.
4. Postgresql.service - status = active
5. К сожалению я в принципе не силен в консоли и в программировании в частности, поэтому возникает много вопросов по установке стека (на всякий случай, стек - python 3.9, pyramid (+jinja2), postgresql, react)
6. Ошибка выдаётся на этапе запуска файла ".py"

```
(env) root@swd:~/pyramid_sites/hello_world# python application.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 16, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM demo")
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "demo" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM demo
```

=========

Буду рад, если сможете помочь (дать гайд пошаговый или иным образом).

Comment: Ошибку в вопрос добавьте (текстом. Не скриншотом)

Comment: @Namerek обновил. 
Спасибо за совет

Comment: Укажите перед именем таблицы имя схемы в которой находится эта таблица. Например `my_schema.demo`.